# How can I know if there is no item selected in a listview?

Tags: listview, excel, vba

I have a delete button in a userform that removes the selected item from the listview. The problem is that when there isn't an item selected (at least it is not highlighted) it removes the first item. How can I know if there is no item selected, so I can avoid removing anything?

Here is what I've tried, and it still removes the first Item when there isn't anything selected.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonDelete_Click()
    If Not (ListView1.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then
       ListView1.ListItems.Remove ListView1.SelectedItem.Index
   End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

The problem seems to be that there is always an item selected. So, new question, how can I unselect the item when the user clicks outside the listView?

Comment: Try 'ListView1.SelectedItem = -1' instead of 'ListView1.SelectedItem = Nothing'.  I didn't put this as a solution because I'm not sure it's correct!  But, it should be quick to try.

Comment: @jerussell No. The problem seems to be that there is always an item selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unselect an item in the same manner as determining if there wasn't anything selected.

For example:

```
Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1
```

Will unselect anything that is selected in ListBox1.  Notice that this is for ListBoxes, I haven't worked with ListViews but I imagine the same would apply.  Of course you'll need to put this somewhere.  The easiest place is to put it in `Private Sub UserForm_Click()` But I wouldn't recommend that because then anytime somebody clicks on the userform after selection it would clear the selection.  The best place to put it would be in `Private Sub ListBox1_Click()` and then determine if the one that was clicked was already selected.  In which case you write code to deselect it...

Confirmed this works with ListBoxes (haven't with ListViews):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Not (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1) Then
        Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex)
    End If
End Sub

'Will unselect any selection when user clicks anywhere on the userform (but not on a control ON the userform)
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "asdf"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "basdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: That works better, but still not the expected behaviour. If you select an item, then click on a textbox in another part of the form, the item will not be highlighted anymore, but when you click delete it will remove the item, because it is still selected (even if it is not highlighted). I could write that line of code for every textbox, label, etc of the form, but that doesn't seem like the best option.

Comment: Are you using your original IF THEN statement that you posted in your question or the one that I suggested later? I was able to test it with ListBoxes and it works fine with this code (poor editing) I will put it in my answer as well):`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Not (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1) Then
        Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "asdf"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "basdf"
End Sub`

Comment: yes, that works, the problem is that when the user clicks on a control, the item is still selected but the highlight is gone, so the user can't tell which item will be removed when he clicks delete.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing that problem with my code example.  It is either a difference between ListBoxes and ListViews or a difference with code.  Again, which If statement are you using? The `If Not (ListView1.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then` statement is likely not correct, because it will never be `Nothing`. If there is no selection then it will be -1.

Comment: I am using ListView1.SelectedItem Is Nothing, and it works fine. Instead of  ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 I use        ListView1.SelectedItem = Nothing, that unselects it, I already checked.

Comment: All I can suggest is to use a ListBox.  Are you getting any benefit by using a ListView rather than a ListBox?